# How to save C program output?

Tags: c, output

I have compiled and run this C program to read the data from a MPPT solar charge controller, connected to a raspberry pi.

https://github.com/anschoewe/morningstar-sunsaver-mppt#readme

I can read all the data no problem, but when i run either of the following commands to save the data I get a  'no such file or directory' message.

```
./sunsaver > output/snapshot_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)

./sunsaver > output/logs_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
```

Do I need to create a file or directory to save to ? and if so where?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Output redirection (`>`) doesn't create directories. So yes, you need to create `output` directory yourself:

```
mkdir -p output
```